# trouble assigning value to nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, variable-assignment

I have a nested hash I want to assign a value to, but ruby keeps complaining about it.

the hash:

```
 data = {
    name: contact.xpath('./span[1]').text.delete("\r\n").strip,
    email: contact.xpath('./a').text,
    offices: [
        postal: contact.text.split("\r\n")[4].strip, 
        tel: /(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})/.match(contact).to_s     
    ],
    url: url
 }
```

my assignment

```
data[:offices][:postal] = ""
```

error:

```
Line 42 - data[:offices][:postal] = "" -- in `[]='
#<TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer>
```

I've tried a handful of other syntaxes, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: show your data Hash here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
offices: [
        postal: contact.text.split("\r\n")[4].strip, 
        tel: /(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})/.match(contact).to_s     
    ],
```

That is not a nested hash. Use curly braces:

```
offices: {
        postal: contact.text.split("\r\n")[4].strip, 
        tel: /(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})/.match(contact).to_s     
    },
```

Comment: Read the doc. (Curly) braces are for hashes, (square) brackets are for arrays. There is no such thing as "square braces".

Comment: For what it's worth, if you use square braces, Ruby will automatically insert curly braces, so you'll end up with a single-value array containing a single hash.